# C# Properties window does't appear

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

The program worked on the original computer. After moving to another computer, the properties window shows the below error.

> An error occurred trying to load the project properties window. Close
> the window and try again. Value cannot be null.Parameter name: val

Does anyone have any idea what this might cause and how to solve it?

Comment: Use the debugger to find out which value is null!

Comment: TaW so you're saying he should debug Visual Studio?

Comment: @TaW  It's the Project's Properties pane. Probably *something* has tampered with the `.csproj` file, but I don't think I've ever seen this one :) -- Close VS, delete the hidden `.vs` folder which is inside the upper folder, where the `.sln` file is usually located. Try to restart running the `.sln` file and in the VS IDE, Clean Solution/Rebuild Solution.

Comment: And check the contents of the .csproj file, if nothing obvious turns up, you might considering adding the contents to this question, perhaps someone can spot something wrong, assuming the problem is in that file that is.

Comment: Right click your project file and see if it is blocked as a security precaution.
If its properties general tap's bottom section looks like this one ( https://i.ibb.co/8m5zVcX/Unblock.jpg ) unblock all the files in the directory.